# remove leading 0 before decimal point and return as a number- javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal-point

**Problem**

I need to return a number in the format of .66 (from an entered value which includes the leading zero, e.g. 0.66)

It must be returned as an integer with the decimal point as the first character.

what method in JavaScript can help me do this?

**What have I tried?**

I've tried converting it toString() and back to parseInt() but including the decimal point makes it return NaN.

I've tried adding various radix (10, 16) to my parseInt() - also unsuccessful

**Sample Code**

```
const value = 0.66;

if(value < 1) {
    let str = value.toString().replace(/^0+/, '');
    // correctly gets '.66'
    return parseInt(str)
}

//result NaN
```

**Expectations**

I expect an output of the value with the leading 0 removed
e.g. 0.45 --> .45 or 0.879 --> .879

**Current Observations**

Output is NaN

Comment: A true integer will always be represented by a leading zero in decimal values. No matter how hard you try, you can only present your expectation as a string.

Comment: you should cut 0 in view layer from a string. the value will remain .66 or 0.66 or 00000.66, all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue #1:
0.66 is not an Integer. An Integer is a whole number, this is a floating-point number.

Issue #2:
You cannot have a number in JavaScript that starts with a decimal point.
Even if you change your `parseInt` to be `parseFloat`, it will still return 0.66 as a result.

What you're asking just isn't possible, if you want a number to start with a decimal point then it has to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a quick solution, you may try to do this:

```
let a = 0.45;
// split on decimal, at index 1 you will find the number after decimal
let b = a.toString().split('.')[1];
```

Comment: Just note this will return `45`, not `.45`. And this won't work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Repondents are correct that this can't be done while preserving a number type. but if all you want is display, I think the easiest answer with a number like "0.6652342" is going to be using the substring() method, which will also let you do precision at the same time:

```
const num = 0.6652342
const display = num.toString().substring(1, 5)
// '.665'
```

(Lots of caveats: whether your numbers can be counted on to all be decimal and < 1, you may need to pad with extra zeros, etc.)